# xamarin form : Filter dynamically a list of Model with different value of the list every time a function is called

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am looking a way to filter a list with different value from Model List every time I call a fonction

Here is an example :

My model look like this :

```
public class Student
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string Game { get; set; }
}
```

What I looking :

I would like to filter the list **MystudentList**  with different Name of students in the list (I can have same student name many times).

```
private async void OnFilterByName(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Here I am getting the List model 
            List<Student> MystudentList = await mywordsdatabase.Student();

            // Do something here that filter dynamicaly the list 
            //by different name of student  in MystudentList when calling the function OnFilterByName

            // get unique value of students Name in List 

            StudentNameIntheList= // get the next student Name every time the function is called

            WordSList.ItemsSource = MyWordsListToFilter.Where(student => student.Name == StudentNameIntheList);
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: do you want to pick a student name at random?  Or pick the "next" student each time?

Comment: @Jason I want to pick next each time, I have update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
int ndx = 0;

List<string> MystudentList;

private async void OnFilterByName(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // you should not need to run this every time unless your data constantly changes
   if (MystudentList == null)
      MystudentList = await mywordsdatabase.Student().Select(s => x.Name).Distinct().ToList();

   var StudentNameIntheList = MystudentList[ndx];
   ndx++;

   WordSList.ItemsSource = MyWordsListToFilter.Where(student => student.Name == StudentNameIntheList);
}
```

Comment: In the list I can have many times the same name, I would like to filter with unique Name

Comment: use LINQ Distinct keyword - see expanded example

Comment: the list is some times out of range

Comment: are you checking that ndx is not greater than the length of the list?

Comment: I have added it